# Programa com lista que receba valores indeterminados em python

Tags: python, lista, if

Um programa em `python` que leia e armazene um número indeterminado de valores em uma lista, correspondentes a notas, encerrando a entrada de dados quando for informado um valor igual a -1 (que não deve ser armazenado).

Estou tentando fazer esse programa há uns dias, gostaria de inserir uma quantidade de valores indeterminados na lista, mas até o momento eu só sei usando `for i in range()` e não é como deve ser...

```py
notas = []

for i in range (0,5):
    val = int(input('digite a nota: '))
    if (val < 0):
        print('fim')
    else: notas.append(val)
    print(notas)
```

Esse foi o mais perto que cheguei, além disso também não consegui fazer a lista parar de receber dados após um valor menor que 0 seja enviado.

Comment: o for loop só serve quando você vai repetir um número determinado de vezes. Para repetir enquanto algo acontece ou algo não acontece, você pode usar o `while`

Comment: A solução é basicamente a mesma que tem nos links indicados acima no box azul: use `while True` e quando for para interromper o loop, use `break` (basta ver os exemplos que tem lá e adaptar para o seu caso)

Answer (score 0):

Uma coisa importante que você disse sobre o programa parar: ali no seu código a única coisa que o programa está fazendo é imprimir os resultados na tela, apenas usar `print('fim')` não vai parar a execução.

Agora sobre os laços de repetição, as diferenças básicas dos dois consiste no que o Flavio Moraes disse, vou te explicar:

1. #### For:

   - É necessário saber o número de vezes que se repetirá o código dentro do loop exatamente, ou seja, quando vai acabar. Pode ser usado sobre objetos iteráveis (coleções como listas `[]`, tuplas `()`, dicionários `{}`, geradores como o `range()`, etc)`.

   ```
   # Aqui no caso, o número de vezes que vamos iterar é o tamanho da lista
   # Esta lista possui 4 elementos, então vamos iterar 4 vezes, uma para
   # Cada elemento da coleção.
   for i in [0,1,2,3]:
       print(i)
   ```
2. #### Vamos entender os booleanos:

   - O *booleano* é o tipo de dado que usamos para fazer comparações e as condições. As condições são usadas por exemplo em: `if's`, `elif's` e laços de repetição `while`.

   ```
   True  # Valor verdadeiro em Python
   # ou
   False  # Valor falso em Python
   ```

   - Dica: Você pode explorar o valor booleano das coisas em Python digitando `bool(valor)`. A função `bool` vai retornar o valor para você. Vamos prosseguir com as condições:

   ```
   inteiro = 0  # O valor 0 em Python é False, qualquer outro número é True
   ```

   ```
   string = ""  # Strings vazias "" são False em Python, Strings NÃO vazias são True
   ```

   ```
   # Coleções vazias também são avaliadas como False, mas se tiverem pelo menos um 
   # elemento dentro delas, serão True

   lista = [""]  # True, pois possui um elemento lá dentro
   lista2 = []   # False, pois é uma lista vazia
   ```
3. #### While:

   - Diferentemente do `for`, este laço vai executar o código dentro dele **enquanto** uma condição for atendida. Então, você pode pensar em como você faria sem código, em português mesmo: *"Enquanto eu tiver notas para armazenar, continue. Se o valor for -1, pare de armazenar"*.

   ```
   while condicao == True:
       # Execute o código

   # Dependendo da sua condição, você pode simplesmente colocá-la ali
   # porque o Python já faz a avaliação do valor sem precisar comparar
   # com os operadores relacionais { <,  >,  ==,  =>,  <=,  != }

   while True:
       # Execute o código
   ```

   - Se a condição que está sendo avaliada no laço `while` for `False`, ele será encerrado automaticamente.
4. #### Agora vamos prosseguir para o código em si!

   - Uma boa solução seria escrever da seguinte maneira:

   ```
   notas = []
   valor = int(input("Digite a nota: "))

   while valor != -1:  # Enquanto a entrada não for igual a -1

       # Dessa maneira, nós asseguramos que só valores >= 0 serão aceitos
       # Você também pode delimitar qual é a nota máxima que pode ser inserida
       if valor >= 0 and valor <= 100:  # Neste exemplo, a nota máx. é 100
           notas.append(valor)

       # Inserindo o próximo valor
       valor = int(input("Digite a nota: "))

   print(notas, "\nfim")  # Imprime notas e imprime 'fim' em nova linha
   ```